# Trying to understand a quantum adder

Tags: ibm-q-experience, quantum-circuit

I've implemented a quantum adder and, when I build the results table, I'm having some trouble to understand what's going on. First, I'm using the adder quantum circuit proposed in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2012.09469), which circuit is shown below:

[image: Circuit from the quantum adder]

This is my version, implemented in IBMQE, as shown below:

[image: My adder circuit implemented in IBMQE]

After building the following truth table, I've got the following results:

[image: Truth table that was obtained by me.]

One can verify that there are several wrong outputs from this circuit. My question is: What's wrong in this circuit? If there is nothing wrong, am I interpreting the outputs in a wrong way? How to interpret them correctly?

Comment: Did you run the circuit in a simulator or real device?

Comment: I ran the circuit in a simulator...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The figure you included in your question references the paper [Addition on a Quantum Computer](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0008033) by Draper. Qiskit has implemented this circuit natively, which you can construct as follows.

```python
from qiskit.circuit.library import DraperQFTAdder

adder = DraperQFTAdder(2).decompose()
adder.draw(output="text")
```

```
a_0: ─────────■──────■───────────────────────
              │      │                       
a_1: ─────────┼──────┼────────■──────────────
     ┌──────┐ │P(π)  │        │     ┌───────┐
b_0: ┤0     ├─■──────┼────────┼─────┤0      ├
     │  QFT │        │P(π/2)  │P(π) │  IQFT │
b_1: ┤1     ├────────■────────■─────┤1      ├
     └──────┘                       └───────┘
```

So, looking at your question, it seems like you misplaced the control qubit of a controlled-P qubit, as your second qubit is never acted on by any gate, but be careful to take into account Qiskit's endian convention when thinking about this.

Running this naively for all inputs, I got:

```python
import itertools
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, transpile
from qiskit.quantum_info import Statevector

backend = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')

for l in list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=4)):
    qc = QuantumCircuit(4)
    
    for i, bit in enumerate(l):
        if bit == 1: 
            qc.x(i)
    qc.append(adder, [0, 1, 2, 3])
    qc.measure_all()
    qc = qc.reverse_bits()
    
    job = backend.run(transpile(qc, backend), shots=1024)
    print(f"Input: {l}. Result: {job.result().get_counts()}")
```

```
Input: (0, 0, 0, 0). Result: {'0000': 1024}
Input: (0, 0, 0, 1). Result: {'0001': 1024}
Input: (0, 0, 1, 0). Result: {'0010': 1024}
Input: (0, 0, 1, 1). Result: {'0011': 1024}
Input: (0, 1, 0, 0). Result: {'0101': 1024}
Input: (0, 1, 0, 1). Result: {'0100': 1024}
Input: (0, 1, 1, 0). Result: {'0111': 1024}
Input: (0, 1, 1, 1). Result: {'0110': 1024}
Input: (1, 0, 0, 0). Result: {'1010': 1024}
Input: (1, 0, 0, 1). Result: {'1011': 1024}
Input: (1, 0, 1, 0). Result: {'1001': 1024}
Input: (1, 0, 1, 1). Result: {'1000': 1024}
Input: (1, 1, 0, 0). Result: {'1111': 1024}
Input: (1, 1, 0, 1). Result: {'1110': 1024}
Input: (1, 1, 1, 0). Result: {'1100': 1024}
Input: (1, 1, 1, 1). Result: {'1101': 1024}
```

This, I think, is what you expected in your table if you take into account the endian notation for each register individually (so, e.g., the input `(0, 1, 0, 1)` is doing $(2 + 2) \mod 4 = 0$). But you can check the [documentation](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.library.DraperQFTAdder.html) for the adder in more detail to confirm.